# How can one turn the laptop screen off but keep the LCD screen attached to it working?

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I have a laptop and a LCD screen. I want to keep the laptop screen off while work with the LCD screen unless I want to turn the laptop screen off. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

In **Windows 7**, choose the *Projector Only* option.

[image]

In **Windows 8** and **Windows 10**, choose the *Second screen only* option.

[image]

Comment: in Windows 8 i guess it's called 2nd screen only

Comment: After a few seconds a message comes up "No projector was detected" and the screen is back on.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot then it's some problem with your laptop. I've never seen anything like that since 10 years back when windows 7 first came

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Control Panel** and then choose **System and Security**.

Choose **Power Options** and then select `Choose What Closing the Lid Does` from the left pane.

[image: Windows 7 System Settings]

On `When I close the lid` option select "Do Nothing" for both "On Battery" and for "Plugged in".

Click **Save changes**

That is it, now you can close the laptop screen and keep working on your LCD.

Comment: but if one wants to leave the lid open then it's no help. And it's better to just change "plugged in" to "do nothing"